# rails unable to store html inside json field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to create json and store it inside json field but all html tag gets change to some code

```
 @vs=@tvrs.vsrs.new()
 @vs.jsr = ({"desc": "<html>\n<body>\n<ul>\n  <li>Generate client.</li>\n  <li>In every month. 
             </li>\n  \n</ul>  \n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>"})
 @vs.save()
```

after store it shows:-

```
{"id":11,"jsr":{"desc":"\u003chtml\u003e\n\u003cbody\u003e\n\u003cul\u003e\n  \u003cli\u003eGenerate client.\u003c/li\u003e\n  \u003cli\u003eIn every month.\u003c/li\u003e\n  \n\u003c/ul\u003e  \n\n\n\n\u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"},"tvr_id":1,"created_at":"2020-06-12T04:01:16.116Z","updated_at":"2020-06-12T04:01:16.116Z"}
```

expected output:-

```
{"id":11,"jsr":{"desc": "<html>\n<body>\n<ul>\n  <li>Generate client.</li>\n  <li>In every month. 
             </li>\n  \n</ul>  \n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>"},"tvr_id":1,"created_at":"2020-06-12T04:01:16.116Z","updated_at":"2020-06-12T04:01:16.116Z"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
# let's assume you have a @vs instance variable which has an attribute jsr.
JSON.parse(@vs.jsr)
=> {"desc": "<html>\n<body>\n<ul>\n  <li>Generate client.</li>\n  <li>In every month. </li>\n  \n</ul>  \n\n\n\n</body>\n</html>"}
```

Comment: I used jsonb field instead of json and issue gets resolved.
thank you  for your  response and solution. :)